# How to find an object by ID in an ember template

Tags: ember.js

I have a data structure like this:

```
let colors = {colorArray: [{id: 1, color: "blue"}, {id: 2, color: "red"}], anotherVariable: "anotherValue"}
```

I have an `each` helper like this:

```
{{#each posts as |post|}}
    <div>...</div>
{{/each}}
```

I want to return the object in `colors.colorArray` that corresponds to the ID of the post I'm iterating over. I'm unsure how to go about this. I tried using an ember-composable-helper, but nothing logs (no errors, either). Here is what I tried:

```
{{#each posts as |post|}}
   {{#with (find-by 'id' post.id colors.colorArray) as |post|}}
      {{post}}
   {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

What am I do wrong? Is there another way I could go about this?

Comment: I posted an answer with some options, but in terms of what might be going wrong, can you share why you are using with? Does it still not work if you change the `|post|` and '{{post}}` to use a different name? With is used for renaming template variables and I wonder if reusing the same name is causing a problem.

Comment: Good idea, but I tried changing the name and unfortunately, this did not work. I'll try one of your suggestions below!

Comment: Ok, @ me if you still have trouble later on and want some help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways to approach this:

- you could pass the posts and array to a component. That component should have a computed property that returns the color. Then you use that computed property in the component template
- try using the [let helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/built-in-helpers/#toc_built-in-block-helpers) instead of `with`, if your version of Ember has it. With is very accident prone.
- you could add a computed property directly to the posts model (if you are using models in your app), which returns the correct color. Then, you could do post.color from anywhere in the app. This is good when the color is needed in many places.
- you could write a (normal) helper that takes the post and colors as arguments and returns the color

Composable helpers are really handy for some use cases but this code is well suited to be written without the addon.